# Uniform space probability over the integers

Tags: probability

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are uniformly chosen pairs of integers with $1 \leq X \leq Y \leq3 $. We want to find $P(X+Y \leq 4)$.

#### Attempt

I did a graph first and see that the probability space consists of the points

$$  (1,1),(1,2), (1,3), (2,2), (2,3), (3,3) $$

Now, since we want $X+Y \leq 4 $ (that also satisfy $1 \leq X \leq Y\leq 3 $), we see that only the points

$$ (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,2) $$

satisfy the conditions. Hence,

$$ P(X+Y \leq 4 ) = \frac{ \# event }{\# sample space} = \frac{4}{6} $$

Is this correct? Is this the general way to think about uniform distributions on discrete spaces?

Comment: It seems correct :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is correct.

---

As it is a **uniform discrete distribution**, each of the outcomes in the sample space have identical probability.

So, indeed, in that senario, finding the *ratio of counts* for oucomes in *the event* versus in the *sample space* is the correct way to evaluate the probability for an event.

Plus those are the required outcomes.   All present and correctly counted.